Normal Subgroup criteria
Trying to prove the equivalence of the two following criteria for a subgroup H (of Group G) to be normal.

$aha^{-1} \in H $ for all $a  \in G, h  \in H   \implies aHa^{-1} = H
 $ for all $a  \in G$

The proof begins by asserting that from $aha^{-1} \in H$ also $a^{-1}ha \in H$ follows, however I seem to be missing the step that demonstrates that for all $h \in H $ this shows $h \in aHa^{-1} $

By the assumption of the forward direction you get the inclusion $aHa^{-1}\subset H$ for free (I am assuming this your definition of a normal subgroup). Now let $h\in H$ and $a\in G$, since forward holds for all $a\in G$ we have that $a^{-1}Ha\subset H$ (just plugging in $a:=a^{-1}$ in forward) so $\exists h_1\in H$ such that $a^{-1}ha=h_1$ (since $a^{-1}ha\in a^{-1}Ha$) so $h=ah_1 a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$ and we are done.

@BillIconomou This should be an answer rather than a comment!

The natural definition of a normal subgroup $H$ should be a subgroup $H$ such that the quotient $G/H$ can itself be provided with a group structure. But we give an equivalent definition that is easier to use afterwards, but which on the other hand leads to little technical difficulties at the beginning.
According to OP, the definition $\color{red}{(*)}$ given is :

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup. $H$ is said to be normal instead of saying that $H$ is a subgroup such that $\forall \alpha\in G, \forall h\in H, \alpha h\alpha^{-1}$ is also in $H$.

First observe that for $a\in G, a^{-1}$ is also in $G$ by definition of a group.
So, if $h\in H, a^{-1}h(a^{-1})^{-1}\in H$ by definition $\color{red}{(*)}$, with $\alpha=a^{-1}$.
Otherwise written, $a^{-1}ha=h'$ $\color{green}{(*)}$, with $h'\in H$.
So, $a(a^{-1}ha)a^{-1}=ah'a^{-1}$, by multiplying LHS and RHS of
$\color{green}{(*)}$ left by $a$ and right by $a^{-1}$.
ie $h=ah'a^{-1}$
ie $h\in aHa^{-1}$.
